# How can I use the keras library for recommending most valuable player in PSL

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras

I am working on machine learning system that will recommend the most valuable player to the owner of the teams based on their requirements in Pakistan Super League (PSL). I want to use keras, deep learning library to do that. I searched a lot on Google but can't find it.
Can someone help me by sharing some research papers or site links.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how to ask questions the right way and to learn more about how stackoverflow works.